# Using AJAX to grab JSON data then output data by ElementID on HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, getelementbyid

I am currently new to using AJAX and JSON and I am stuck on something that may be simple to you.

I am to use AJAX to grab data from JSON then from there, I will need to be inputting the data into specified ElementIDs on my HTML Page.

The data is Paragraphs and I am stuck on the Javascript part where I am to grab my data from JSON then to a ElementID on my HTML Document.

JSON

```
{

    "Paragraphs": [

        {
            "Paragraph1": "Hi! I am Person."
        },

        {
            "Paragraph2": "My name is Person and I am a web designer from a Place."
        }

    ]
}
```

JS

```
(function () {


    "use strict";
    // Instantiate new xhr object
    var dataFile = "scripts/app.json";
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', dataFile, true);
    request.addEventListener('readystatechange', function () {
        // wait for file to finish loading
        if (request.readyState === 4) {
            var paragraph = {};

            // read in the json object
            paragraph = JSON.parse(request.responseText);


            // declare local paragraph array container
            var paragraphArray = [];

            // read in the paragraphs array from the json object
            paragraphArray = paragraph.Paragraphs;

            //store
            var paragraphArrayLength = paragraphArray.length;
            //loop
            for (var number = 0; number < paragraphArrayLength; number++) {
                var paragraph = document.getElementById('Paragraph1' + 'Paragraph2' + (number + 1));
                Paragraphs.Paragraph1.innerHTML = paragraphArray[number];
                paragraphs.Paragraph2.innerHTML = paragraphArray[number];
            }
        }
    });
    request.send();

})();
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="text-center">
            <h1 id="Paragraph1"></h1>
            <img src="images/portfolio.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="Cinque Terre" width="150" height="150">
            <p class="lead" id="Paragraph2"></p>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help! Thank you 8)

Comment: Do you want to use the keys in the JSON as the ID of the paragraph to fill in?

Comment: So I have to use AJAX and JSON to input the data from the JSON to my HTML Doc.

Comment: So like for example:

Comment: the ID I set for my <p> is Paragraph1, on my JSON file, I have a paragraph and I set one of them as Paragraph1. When I do that then AJAX with grab my JSON and then input It to my HTML to "Paragraph1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html and javascript both contain errors that need fixing. For example, the html has an extra ul tag and "Paragraphs" should be "paragraphs" in your loop.

Yet, the data format might be the reason you are having a difficult time. You have an array of objects and each object has a key with a different name. And while you can do it that way, it makes it more difficult to work with. In contrast, an array of strings would be far easier. Also see Barmar's solution which another commonly used alternative.

To make it easier to understand, I've removed all the extraneous code, including the loop. The snippet simply writes each paragraph 1 and 2. Yet, some of the other solutions here show you how to loop through the data too.

**Run the snippet to try it.**

```js
// simulated ajax data
var request = {
  responseText: '{"Paragraphs":[{"Paragraph1":"Lions and tigers"},{"Paragraph2":"and bears"}]}'
};


// if (request.readyState === 4) { ...

var paragraph = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
var paragraphArray = paragraph.Paragraphs;

document.getElementById('Paragraph1').innerHTML = paragraphArray[0].Paragraph1;
document.getElementById('Paragraph2').innerHTML = paragraphArray[1].Paragraph2;
```

```html
<h1 id="Paragraph1"></h1>
<p class="lead" id="Paragraph2"></p>
```

Comment: This is what I needed! Thanks! :)

Comment: Hard-coding `.Paragraph1` and `.Paragraph2` doesn't seem very general. Does the API really just return just those 2 paragraphs?

Comment: @Barmar - I completely agree with you, which is why I up voted your more  general solution. Yet, Jeff Atwood (SO founder) makes a good point about [Speculative Generality](http://blog.codinghorror.com/code-smells/) in which he says, "Write code to solve today's problems, and worry about tomorrow's problems when they actually materialize"

Answer (score 1):

This will use the keys in the objects in the `Paragraphs` array as the IDs of the elements to fill in with the values.

```
for (var i = 0; i < paragraphArrayLength; i++) {
    for (var id in paragraphArray[i]) {
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = paragraphArray[i][id];
    }
}
```

The nested loops are necessary because your array elements are objects, and the property names are different in each object. I recommend changing the JSON structure so it's more uniform, e.g.

```
{

    "Paragraphs": [

        {
            "id": "Paragraph1",
            "value": "Hi! I am Person."
        },

        {
            "id": "Paragraph2",
            "value": "My name is Person and I am a web designer from a Place."
        }

    ]
}
```

Or make `Paragraphs` an object instead of an array, where the IDs are the keys of that object.

Comment: up voted as the solution underlines the importance of using a good data format when you have control of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
            for (var number = 0; number < paragraphArrayLength; number++) {
            var paragraph = document.getElementById('Paragraph' + (number + 1);

            paragraph.innerHTML = paragraphArray[number -1].keys['Paragraph' + number];
        }
```

When you iterate the paragraphs, you should set each one to a local var. That way you have 1 paragraph that you are working on, per iteration.

Comment: `paragraphArray[number]` is an object, not a string.